# How to get the text after span elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return the values 1718 and $15.95 but when I run the code below SKU: and Retail Price: are returned in the alert boxes. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var a = $('.description span').first().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text(); 
alert(a);

var b = $('.description span').last().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
alert(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <span>SKU:</span>
  1719
</div>
<div class="description">
  <span>Retail Price:</span>
  $15.95
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are getting the contents inside the span and not outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($(".description").eq(0).contents().eq(2).text().trim());
  console.log($(".description").eq(1).contents().eq(2).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
        <span>SKU:</span>
        1719
</div>
<div class="description">
        <span>Retail Price:</span>
        $15.95
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that works Geetanjali. Thanks. but I tried that code with Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) and it give me error. Any ideas why?

Here is the line of code...

script = "$('.description').eq(1).contents().eq(2).text().trim());"; 

Here is the error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )\n@ about:blank:1:54"

Comment: Never mind... ! too many right parens. Code works perfectly. Can you tell me exactly what your code does?

Answer (score 0):

GRF,

The reason why it's not working is you sku and price are out of span. Try below hope it will help.

```
var a = $('.sku').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).text(); 
alert(a);

var b = $('.price').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
      }).text();
alert(b);

<div class="description">
        <span>SKU:</span>
        <div class='sku'>1719</div>
</div>
<div class="description">
        <span>Retail Price:</span>
        <div class='price'>$15.95<div>
```

Comment: Thanks Altaf, but the script code doesn't work. .sku and .price denote classes that are not in the HTML. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*!
 * Find text within given elements (1st param - selector)
 * while optionally excluding other elements (2nd - exclusion)
 **
 * @param  {String} selector  
 * The reference of the elements (aka tags) to search within.
 **
 * @param  {String} exclusion [optional - default: null] 
 * The reference of the elements to exclude from searching.
 **
 * @return {Array}
 * An array of strings found in search.
 */
```

```js
const txt = (selector, exclusion = null) => {
  // Collect all elements that match {{selector}}ninto a NodeList
  const roots = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  // Declare an empty array
  let text = [];
  /*
  {{element}} label statement will allow `continue` and `break` to
  jump from within a loop to the beginning of another
  */
  element:
  // Iterate each tag of the {{roots}} NodeList
  for (let root of roots) {
    // if {{exclusion}} wasn't passed...
    if (exclusion === null) {
    // Add the text of the current tag ({{root}}) to the {{text}} array
    text.push(root.textContent.trim());
    //Otherwise...
    } else {
      // Collect all text and elements into a HTML Collection
      let nodes = root.childNodes;
      // Iterate each text/element node...
      for (let node of nodes) {
        // if current node is an element...
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
          // if current node matches {{exclusion}}
          if (node.matches(exclusion)) {
            // just skip forward to the next iteration
            continue;
          // Otherwise...
          } else {
            // Redefine​ {{root}} to {{node}}
            root = node;
            // Jump to the label of the outer loop
            continue element;
          }
        // Or if {{node}} is a text node...
        } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
          // Add the text node to {{text}} array
          text.push(node.nodeValue.trim());
        // Otherwise stop iteration of the remaining nodes
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // return a filtered array of strings
  return text.filter(t => t);
}

// Find the text of all <li>
console.log(txt('li'));

// Find the text of all <li> and exclude text of all <label>
console.log(txt('li', 'label'));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>SKU:</label> 1719
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Retail Price:</label> $15.95
  </li>
</ul>
```